# Castle Windsor - Interceptor: call invocation.Proceed twice

Tags: c#, interceptor, castle

We have interceptors on data-changing methods that flush changes to the database after the methods have run. In case of a deadlock, we would like to rerun the methods.

In this simplified example I catch SqlExceptions and in case of a deadlock I try calling `Proceed()` again.

```
try {
  invocation.Proceed();
  if (!isReadOnly) {
    log.Trace("Flushing the unit of work.");
    session.Flush();
  }
} catch (GenericADOException ex) {
  var sqle = ADOExceptionHelper.ExtractDbException(ex) as SqlException;
  if (sqle != null) {
  if (sqle.Number == deadlockVictim) {
    invocation.Proceed();
  }
}
```

This fails due to Castle noticing that I'm trying to call `Proceed()` a second time and throws an exception starting with:

> This is a DynamicProxy2 error: invocation.Proceed() has been called
>   more times than expected.

How can I call `Proceed` again after catching the exception?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without [a ugly hack](http://www.primordialcode.com/index.php/2010/01/19/castle-dynamicproxy-dirty-trick-call-invocation-proceed-multiple-times-interceptor/) that resets the interceptor count of your interceptor chain, but if you really need to you must:

- get into the IInterception class and change the `currentInterceptorIndex` (it changed name since the article was published) to -1, in whichever way you want. The article author uses an extension method
- call the proceed method again after solving whichever problem in your DB

This is really *really* **really** not recommended; you should at least setup some kind of upper limit to the call loop of the method to avoid some case where your DB call never gets out of the proceed-reset-proceed flow

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We do have an upper limit. This sounds like a very bad idea. I'm guessing ther isn't any good practice / a pattern published on this?

Comment: @doker I think that this is a case where it depends on your architecture. If you have a message-based system then you can easily feed the message back into the pipeline for processing. If not then it depends on how commands are processed